# Automatically add a YAML Front Matter in Typora

Tags: yaml, markdown, yaml-front-matter

I am using Hexo to post my blog online and Hexo requires me to include a YAML Front Matter in my `.md` file so it can render the title in my online blog.
Manually adding the YAML Front Matter `title` file is tedious. How can I automatically generate the `title` according to the name of the `.md` file?

Like when I create a `Managing dependencies.md` file, Typora would automatically add the `title: Managing dependencies` YAML Front Matter as I open it for the first time. Or is there any script that enables me to use only a single shortcut to generate it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjZZr.png)